# how can I export specific fields from mongodb using python and save it into a dataframe

Tags: python, json, database, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am working on really messy data in MongoDB. I want to take out some data by going deep in the hierarchy. but going in the hierarchy for every data object is not the same. how can I export all of its form all data objects?

an instance of the data looks something like this

```py
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ebfe617c2b8d71c317b213b"),
    "testResults" : {
        "callStats" : {
            "registrationStartTime" : "2020-5-16 13:8:15.619",
            "registrationEndTime" : "2020-5-16 13:8:17.489",
            "callInitTime" : "2020-5-16 13:8:22.805",
            "callRingTime" : "2020-5-16 13:9:9.475",
            "callAnsTime" : "2020-5-16 13:9:12.643",
            "callEndTime" : "2020-5-16 13:9:18.615",
            "from" : "192.168.1.1",
            "to" : "130.211.114.18"
        },
        "periodic" : {
            "7472-1" : {
                "sender" : {
                    "1906108488" : [ 
                        {
                            "startTime" : "2020-5-14 22:4:13.42",
                            "endTime" : "2020-5-14 22:4:23.23",
                            "values" : [ 
                                {
                                    "kind" : "audio",
                                    "ssrc" : "1906108488",
                                    "isRemote" : false,
                                    "mediaType" : "audio",
                                    "trackIdentifier" : "357de7f0-0d99-4061-aacb-6cfbf14dcbec",
                                    "mediaSourceId" : "RTCAudioSource_1",
                                    "remoteSource" : false,
                                    "ended" : false,
                                    "detached" : false,
                                    "echoReturnLoss" : -30,
                                    "echoReturnLossEnhancement" : 0.175512,
                                    "transportId" : "RTCTransport_0_1",
                                    "packetsSent" : 0,
                                    "packetsSent_per_s" : 0,
                                    "retransmittedPacketsSent" : 0,
                                    "bytesSent" : 0,
                                    "bytesSent_per_s" : 0,
                                    "retransmittedBytesSent" : 0
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "kind" : "audio",
                                    "ssrc" : "1906108488",
                                    "isRemote" : false,
                                    "mediaType" : "audio",
                                    "trackIdentifier" : "357de7f0-0d99-4061-aacb-6cfbf14dcbec",
                                    "mediaSourceId" : "RTCAudioSource_1",
                                    "remoteSource" : false,
                                    "ended" : false,
                                    "detached" : false,
                                    "echoReturnLoss" : -30,
                                    "echoReturnLossEnhancement" : 0.175512,
                                    "transportId" : "RTCTransport_0_1",
                                    "packetsSent" : 0,
                                    "packetsSent_per_s" : 0,
                                    "retransmittedPacketsSent" : 0,
                                    "bytesSent" : 0,
                                    "bytesSent_per_s" : 0,
                                    "retransmittedBytesSent" : 0
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "kind" : "audio",
                                    "ssrc" : "1906108488",
                                    "isRemote" : false,
                                    "mediaType" : "audio",
                                    "trackIdentifier" : "357de7f0-0d99-4061-aacb-6cfbf14dcbec",
                                    "mediaSourceId" : "RTCAudioSource_1",
                                    "remoteSource" : false,
                                    "ended" : false,
                                    "detached" : false,
                                    "echoReturnLoss" : -30,
                                    "echoReturnLossEnhancement" : 0.175512,
                                    "transportId" : "RTCTransport_0_1",
                                    "packetsSent" : 0,
                                    "packetsSent_per_s" : 0,
                                    "retransmittedPacketsSent" : 0,
                                    "bytesSent" : 0,
                                    "bytesSent_per_s" : 0,
                                    "retransmittedBytesSent" : 0
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "kind" : "audio",
                                    "ssrc" : "1906108488",
                                    "isRemote" : false,
                                    "mediaType" : "audio",
                                    "trackIdentifier" : "357de7f0-0d99-4061-aacb-6cfbf14dcbec",
                                    "mediaSourceId" : "RTCAudioSource_1",
                                    "remoteSource" : false,
                                    "ended" : false,
                                    "detached" : false,
                                    "echoReturnLoss" : -30,
                                    "echoReturnLossEnhancement" : 0.175512,
                                    "transportId" : "RTCTransport_0_1",
                                    "packetsSent" : 0,
                                    "packetsSent_per_s" : 0,
                                    "retransmittedPacketsSent" : 0,
                                    "bytesSent" : 0,
                                    "bytesSent_per_s" : 0,
                                    "retransmittedBytesSent" : 0
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "kind" : "audio",
                                    "ssrc" : "1906108488",
                                    "isRemote" : false,
                                    "mediaType" : "audio",
                                    "trackIdentifier" : "357de7f0-0d99-4061-aacb-6cfbf14dcbec",
                                    "mediaSourceId" : "RTCAudioSource_1",
                                    "remoteSource" : false,
                                    "ended" : false,
                                    "detached" : false,
                                    "echoReturnLoss" : -30,
                                    "echoReturnLossEnhancement" : 0.175512,
                                    "transportId" : "RTCTransport_0_1",
                                    "packetsSent" : 0,
                                    "packetsSent_per_s" : 0,
                                    "retransmittedPacketsSent" : 0,
                                    "bytesSent" : 0,
                                    "bytesSent_per_s" : 0,
                                    "retransmittedBytesSent" : 0
                                }, 
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried the code below. but this code give a lot of data that is not needed and also it gives the data in the hierarchal json format. findin the desired data in that is again a very difficult task

```py
def  webrtcData(user,start_time,end_time,count):
   dnsData = mon_client().find_query_voip_selective('webrtc_test', {},count,{"start_timestamp":1, "testResults.periodic":1})
   data = json.loads(json.dumps(list(dnsData), cls=JSONEncoder))  
   return {"data":data}
```

and the other function which is used in the above code is given below

```py
def find_query_voip_selective(self, collection, query,count,selective={}):
   db = self.mongo_client.get_database(self.db_name)
   collection = db.get_collection(collection)
   if selective:
       if count!="":
           data= collection.find(query, selective).sort([("_id", pymongo.DESCENDING)]).limit(count)
           data=[i for i in data]
       else:
           data= collection.find(query, selective).sort([("_id", pymongo.DESCENDING)])
           data=[i for i in data]
   else:
       data= collection.find(query)
       data=[i for i in data]
   return data
```

My expected output is a dataframe with these columns

```py
    kind    ssrc    isRemote    mediaType   trackIdentifier        mediaSourceId    remoteSource    ended   detached    echoReturnLoss  echoReturnLossEnhancement   transportId packetsSent packetsSent_per_s   retransmittedPacketsSent    bytesSent   bytesSent_per_s retransmittedBytesSent
0   audio   1906108488  false   audio   357de7f0-0d99-4061-aacb-6cfbf14dcbec    RTCAudioSource_1    false   false   false   -30 0.175512    RTCTransport_0_1    0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: I have updated the question now you can see the expected output @deadshot

Comment: but the code you are tried is completely different from the output you are expecting

Comment: yes because I cannot go further on how to extract the desired data from a messy hierarchy of the data.

Comment: do you want create the dataframe from above json?

Comment: yes but as I said specific data needs to be there in data frame

Comment: Have you tried formatting the output data of your query with an aggregate, with $unwind and $project operators